# Hide View in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: xcode, swift, uicollectionview, cell

Can anyone tell my it won't hide my UIView in the simulator?
The code is functioning and it prints the numbers I added to the functions but it still doesn't work.

Basically I want to tap the cell and the greyView in the cell should disappear.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let lpgr = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleTap(_:)))
        lpgr.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = true
        lpgr.delegate = self
        AlarmCollection.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)

    }


    // MARK: UICollectionViewCell

    func handleTap(gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureReconizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
            return
        }

        let p = gestureReconizer.locationInView(AlarmCollection)
        let indexPath = AlarmCollection.indexPathForItemAtPoint(p)

        if let index = indexPath {
            var cell = AlarmCollection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index)
            // do stuff with your cell, for example print the indexPath
            print(index.row)
            updateView(indexPath!)
        } else {
            print("Could not find index path")
        }
    }



    func updateView(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = AlarmCollection.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AlarmItemCell
        cell.greyView.hidden = true
        print("2")

    }
```

EDIT:

```
// MARK: UICollectionViewCell



func handleTap(gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureReconizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        return
    }

    let p = gestureReconizer.locationInView(AlarmCollection)
    let indexPath = AlarmCollection.indexPathForItemAtPoint(p)

    if let index = indexPath {
        var cell = AlarmItemCell()
        // do stuff with your cell, for example print the indexPath
        print(index.row)
        updateView()
    } else {
        print("Could not find index path")
    }
}




func updateView(cell: UICollectionViewCell) {
    if let cell = cell as? AlarmItemCell {
        cell.greyView.hidden = true
    }
    print("2")
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
if let index = indexPath {
            let cell = AlarmCollection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index)
            updateView(cell!)


        }
```

Comment: You should clean up your code before posting. Keeping unnecessary code like `didReceiveMemoryWarning()` and unneeded comments like `//Do additional setup after loading...` makes it more difficult to read and may take away someone willing to help. Maybe you can edit your post?

Comment: Ok will do thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the cell that you are getting from your collection view to reference the greyView.

For example, change your `updateView` function to:

```
func updateView(cell: UICollectionViewCell) {
    if let cell = cell as? AlarmItemCell {
      cell.greyView.hidden = true
    }
    print("2")
}
```

Then pass the cell you got here `var cell = AlarmCollection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index)` to the function.
The way you are doing it now isn't grabbing the correct cell as far as I can tell.

EDIT:

```
if let index = indexPath, 
   let cell = AlarmCollection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index) {
    updateView(cell)
} else {
    print("Could not find index path or cell")
}
```

Comment: You should also avoid force casting and force unwrapping as much as possible to avoid crashes and unexpected bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I'm still kind of stuck could you tell me what I'm still doing wrong? @ebearden I updated the main Question

Comment: Does your `updateView` function get called and if so, do you make it into the block that hides the view?

Comment: I think what you want is, based on your edit:
   var cell = AlarmCollection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index)
   updateView(cell)

Comment: Wow thank you so much! But apparently that doesn't work without force unwrapping. I will put the working code in the edit.

Comment: Cool. I added a way to avoid that in my edit. Glad it works

Comment: It that works for you could you accept my answer. Internet points being what they are :)

Comment: Sure. But your last edit only works if I add a ! after (indexPath

Comment: Oops. It should have been index. Fixed